# How to make buttons from one form affect a listview in another one?

Tags: c#, listview

I want to have buttons in one form, then as I click on them, an item is added to a list in another form.

This is my current code, take in mind that in this code the buttons are in the same form as the listview, and I want to move either to a new one:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("Panama");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("Brazil");
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

How do I do so when the button is clicked, the list in another form gets the item added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the other forms from the form that invokes the action.
One way is to expose the ListView as a property on the Form itself and the just reference it via the Form

From Form1

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2Instance.MyListView.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

In Form2 add the following wrapper to expose the original listView

```
public ListView MyListView{get{return this.ListView1;}}
```

Comment: It works, but it gives me the Error "ein.Form2.listView1' is inaccessible due to its protection level" How do I fix that? Sorry, this is my first C# project

Comment: Make it a public property instead, so that you have access to it. If your ListView is declared as a private property you won't have access to it from outside the class

Answer (score 2):

two ways to achieve this:

first you have a reference to the other form and its listview, and call the listview to add/remove item straightaway when the button is clicked in the current form.

second use event: when the button is clicked, raise an event which is subscribed by the other form, and in the handler, do whatever you like (such as add/remove item to your list view according to the event data). for event, ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have Form1 and Form2 where Form1 is the one with the buttons and Form2 contains the ListView. At the moment when you create Form2 you have to save a reference to this instance of Form2 in Form1.

```
public class Form1
    {
        private Form2 form2;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.form2 = new Form1();
            this.form2.Show();
        }
    }

    public class Form2
    {
        public Form2()
        {

        }

        public void AddItemToListView(string itemName)
        {
            // Check if itemName is valid and add it to your listView
        }
        public void RemoveItemFromListViewAt(int position)
        {
            // Check if the position is valid and remove the item at the position
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't reference one form from another just to add an item to a list.  :)

Building off of Rex's answer above, you could implement the Domain Event Pattern (http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html)

A simple (rudimentary) implementation would have a singleton class managing the event / firing of the event:

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Class representing a single source for domain events within an application.
/// </summary>
public class DomainEventSource
{
    #region Fields

    private static readonly Lazy<DomainEventSource> source = new Lazy<DomainEventSource>( () => new DomainEventSource() );

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a reference to the singleton instance of the <see cref="DopmainEventSource"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value> A<see cref="DomainEventSource"/> object.</value>
    public static DomainEventSource Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return source.Value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called to indicate an event should be triggered with a given item name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">A <see cref="string"/> value.</param>
    public void FireEvent( string name )
    {
        if ( this.AddItem != null )
        {
            this.AddItem( source, new AddItemEvent( name ) );
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    /// <summary>
    /// Event raised when add item is needed.
    /// </summary>
    public EventHandler<AddItemEvent> AddItem;

    #endregion
}
```

And then wiring up for and calling events like:

```
DomainEventSource.Instance.AddItem += ( s, a ) => Console.WriteLine( "Event fired with name: " + a.ItemName );
```

DomainEventSource.Instance.FireEvent( "Thing" );

With this, you have to keep in mind that events are a easy source of memory leaks.  If you register this, make sure you unregister it.

Answer (score -2):

make listView of form as a static one

public static ListView listview1=........

then you can Access that ListView  from another form like follows

Form1.listview1.Add(value);

Comment: Yeah! Making *everything* static would also be an option.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will keep state between Forms that are opened and closed multiple times. Static is generally not a good idea for this IMO