# delete listview item from another form - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to delete listview item from the main form
after I click on btn in another form
How can I do it?

Main Form

```
        private void DeleteSelectedProductRclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(ProductListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);
        string prodname = ProductListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        string prodid = ProductListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
        string cutsentence = null;

        for (int i = 7; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            cutsentence = FirstWords(prodname, i);
            if (cutsentence.Length <= 45)
            {
                cutsentence = cutsentence + " ...";
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        DeleteProductForm mg = new DeleteProductForm(id, cutsentence, prodid);
        mg.Show();
    }
```

Sec Form

```
        private void Yesbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EbaySellBL.EbayProduct.DeleteProduct(this.ID);
        this.Close();
        //ProductListView.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make buttons from one form affect a listview in another one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627657/how-to-make-buttons-from-one-form-affect-a-listview-in-another-one)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a control (your listview) public by opening the Properties tab in the winform designer and by changing the "Modifiers" property to "Public".

Now you can access it from another form.

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133894/c-sharp-using-winform-controls-in-another-class/)

Comment: Or, I usually think it's better practice to make a public property that gives access to the `ListView`..

Comment: @DangerZone Indeed it is, I tried to keep it simple though.